# If the output force to input force increases when we use a lever, what decreases? (mechanical advantage)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, statics

I'm stuck on this one, does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What changes when you use a lever? You don't just get a larger force. Same goes for the other simple machines: pulley, inclined plane, screw, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the output displacement is reduced in the same proportion by which the output force is increased over the input force. This conserves energy.